# Does anyone have working batch files for FlashDevelop to create an AAB file?

Tags: actionscript-3, air

Does anyone have working batch files for FlashDevelop to create an AAB file?

I have been following the instructions in the Harman AIR 33.1 Release Notes 1, Section 7.

I made some changes to the Packager.bat and PackageApp.bat files. I feel like I’m getting close to a result, but I am currently receiving this error:

Bundle tool failed:Error while parsing the flags: Syntax error: flags should start with -- (appname\dist\aab3710715705286998448.aab)

The command being called is:

adt -package -target aab -storetype pkcs12 -keystore "cert\Cert.p12" -storepass abcabcabc "dist\appname.aab" "application.xml" -C bin . -C "icons" . -extdir ane/

I’m guessing the syntax for flags is a bit different between the aab and apk and I need to move things around a bit. Does anyone know what it could be?

As a side note, if anyone using IntelliJ or VSCode could chime in, how smooth is the AAB creation process in those IDEs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue thanks to a response in the Starling forums.

For anyone who may stumble onto this post with the same problem: The aab bundling doesn’t work if you have spaces in your project path.